# Weird UnsupportedOperationException java error in cfdump

Tags: java, exception, coldfusion

When we log errors we like to collect some info about the state of the application to help us diagnose the cause. In our error logging code we have something like this:

```
<cfset local.scopeList = "CGI,FORM,URL,APPLICATION,REQUEST,COOKIE,CLIENT" />    
<cfsavecontent variable="local.errorInfo">
  <cfloop list="#local.scopeList#" index="local.scope">
    <cfdump var="#Evaluate(local.scope)#" />
  </cfloop>
</cfsavecontent>
```

There's actually a bit more to it than that (we check whether local.scope is defined before trying to cfdump it and some other things related to our info gathering, but those are the basic bits). `local.errorInfo` is part of what we squirrel away for later viewing.

Occasionally we'll see an exception come through and the TagContext shows that the error happened on the cfdump line in our code.  The interesting thing is that in the TagContext our code is the third item.  The first two are in \WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm and their RAW_TRACE info looks like

`at cfdump2ecfm1568701689._factor4({path on server}\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm)`

and

`at cfdump2ecfm1568701689._factor1({path on server}\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm)`

The actual Message item in the exception struct is empty string and the type is `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

The strange thing is that if we run this exact code manually it clears up the issue and things go on fine for a while, but when it starts happening again it will continue to happen until we 'give it a kick' by running the code manually again.  It's like something goes wonky and it can't recover until we help it.

We are on CF10 and AFAIK we haven't upgraded either CF or Java any time close to the time when this first started happening.

My question is what is causing this?  (Bonus if you can explain why our workaround temporarily 'fixes' it.)

**Edit** Here's a bit of the stack trace, starting at the top:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at
>   coldfusion.thread.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getLocalPort(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:446)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.CgiScope.resolve(CgiScope.java:146) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CgiScope.resolveName(CgiScope.java:328) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.Scope.get(Scope.java:60) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.DotResolver.resolve(DotResolver.java:45) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.DotResolver.resolve(DotResolver.java:72) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.DotResolver.resolve(DotResolver.java:88) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_resolveSplitName(NeoPageContext.java:1033)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_resolveDottedName(NeoPageContext.java:1011)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.findAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:657)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.findAttribute(NeoPageContext.java:630)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.IsDefined(CFPage.java:925) at
>   cfdump2ecfm1568701689$funcDUMPSTRUCT.runFunction(E:\cf10_final\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm:1957)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
>   coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:518) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2624) at
>   cfdump2ecfm1568701689$funcHANDLESTRUCT.runFunction(E:\cf10_final\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm:781)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
>   coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:518) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2624) at
>   cfdump2ecfm1568701689$funcRENDEROUTPUT.runFunction(E:\cf10_final\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm:693)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472) at
>   coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2659) at
>   cfdump2ecfm1568701689._factor18(E:\cf10_final\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cftags\dump.cfm:565) at.....

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` is a generic exception used by many classes. So the cause could be many things. Like the name implies, it is used to indicate something you are doing (or something cfdump is doing) is not supported. Can you post the complete stack trace? It might provide some clues about *what* operation is causing the problem. Also, are you able to tell what `local` element is being evaluated when the error occurs? I am wondering if it a) might be related to usage of `evaluate` and b) whether you really need `evaluate`. Could you use struct notation `local[keyName]` instead?

Comment: Ah, yes - I had intended to include a bit of the stack trace and forgot.  I'll update the question with that.  As for avoiding Evaluate I like that idea.  Rather than treating a list of strings representing the scopes we want dumped maybe I can use an array of the actual scopes instead.  I'll give that a shot and see how it fares.  thanks!

Comment: What we want are the actual scopes, where we started with a string that has the same name as the scope we want.  If we take it out then the code becomes a cfdump of the strings "CGI", "FORM", etc. which isn't useful and probably won't exhibit the issue since now we're trying to dump something entirely different (and much more simple).

Comment: Yeah, I did not notice the you were dumping other scopes, not just keys in the local scope. If this is just for debugging you could probably just dump `getPageContext().getCFScopes()` (returns an array). IIRC it includes all common scopes.

Comment: We've now both unrolled the loop and added a try/catch around each scope eval so we can see which one(s) are giving us grief.  I'd love to uncover the underlying cause, but for now this is getting us by.  I believe we intend to go back and investigate once we collect enough data points.  I'll either accept an answer at that point or post a solution to the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe scopes are not supposed to be dumped this way.  Unroll your cfloop and you should be fine.

Unlike variables, scopes are a different kind of animal.  I think it's unnatural to reference a scope itself dynamically and therefore I'm not surprised that `Evaluate` is tripped up.

Comment: I've floated that idea and we may end up trying it (we want to do a bit more research before doing a full prod build - it's only happening on our prod server).  Can you offer background info or references on why you say scopes aren't supposed to be dumped this way?  That may help us track down what the cause is.  Most of the time it works fine (which doesn't necessarily indicate that it's for sure safe).  I'm curious about the intermittent nature of it. BTW if unrolling the loop ends up working I'll accept this as the answer fo sho

Comment: I do not know that there is anything *technically* wrong with the code above, but .. how well it works probably depends on the values contained in the various structures. I suspect the usage of `evaluate()` may be the cause of the problems here...